# Adding dynamic data to a table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Database schema looks like

```
ID  Link_name  Description
```

and wish The link name from the database to load in the table as

```
-----------------------------
Link_name1   |  Link_name2   |
------------------------------

-----------------------------
Link_name3   |  Link_name4   |
------------------------------
```

But the code

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <?php 
    require('config.php');
    $datae = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY id DESC")or die(mysql_error());  while($infoe = mysql_fetch_array( $datae )) {?>
  <tr>
      <td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="93%" class="main_text">

          <h3><?php echo $infoe['Link_name']; }?><hr><br></h3>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Output as

```
--------------
Link_name1   | 
--------------

---------------
Link_name2   |  
--------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what are you asking for, but just a guess:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<?php 
    require('config.php');
    $datae = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY id DESC")or die(mysql_error());  

    $leftRight = 'left';
    while($infoe = mysql_fetch_array( $datae )) {
      if (  $leftRight == 'left') {
          echo '<tr><td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>';
          echo '<td width="93%" class="main_text">';
          echo '<h3>'.$infoe['Link_name'].'<hr><br></h3>';
          echo '</td>';
          $leftRight = 'right';
      } else {
          echo '<td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>';
          echo '<td width="93%" class="main_text">';
          echo '<h3>'.$infoe['Link_name'].'<hr><br></h3>';
          echo '</td></tr>';
          $leftRight = 'left';
      }
  } 
  if (  $leftRight == 'right') echo '<td></td><td></td></tr>'; ?>
</table>
```

**EDIT** If you need to format N column table:

```
    $current = 1;
    $columnLimit = 3; //you can set any number of column to output
    while($infoe = mysql_fetch_array( $datae )) {
      if ( $current == 1) {
          echo '<tr><td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>';
          echo '<td width="93%" class="main_text">';
          echo '<h3>'.$infoe['Link_name'].'<hr><br></h3>';
          echo '</td>';
          $current++; 
      } elseif ( $current == $columnLimit) { {
          echo '<td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>';
          echo '<td width="93%" class="main_text">';
          echo '<h3>'.$infoe['Link_name'].'<hr><br></h3>';
          echo '</td></tr>';
          $current = 1; 
      } else {
          echo '<td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>';
          echo '<td width="93%" class="main_text">';
          echo '<h3>'.$infoe['Link_name'].'<hr><br></h3>';
          echo '</td>';
          $current++; 
      }

  } 
  while ( $current!=1 && $current <= $columnLimit) {
     if ($current != $columnLimit)
        echo '<td></td>';
     else
        echo '<td></td></tr>';
     $current++;
  }
```

?>

Comment: sir what if i want to do the same for 3 columns?

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operator (http://php.net/manual/de/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

With that you know if your current data entry is a odd or even number. so you can say something like: If your a even dataset then close the current row and open a new one.